# Error when calculating more than 1 input

Tags: list-manipulation, scoping, procedural-programming

I'm trying to solve a problem where I can't do more than 1 calculation inside a `Module` here. I have a list of numbers where `v={143.5,66.4,...}` that needs to run into the `Module` and gives the result of each number entered in `v`.

My problem is when `v={143.5}`, I seems to get the answer that I'm looking for which is

> ```
> {{{{{0.00134915}}, {{-1.00001}}, {{0.0112934}}, {{-16.9408}}}, 
> {{{-0.499981}}, {{0.998664}}, {{-1765.75}}, {{-0.0113652}}}}}
> ```

When I set `v={143.5,66.4,...}`, instead I get an error of

> `Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in -3033.72 {54.3206,117.395} {1/2 (15590. +σ^2)} cannot be combined.`

I've tried checking my code but it seems to work with 1 input and only buggy when it's more than 1 input in `v`. What I'm trying to do is to calculate different value of `q1` inside the module. Since `q1=1/v` where `v={143.5, 66.4, 29.8, 5.6}`. Meaning here there's 4 different `q1` variables that need to be looped and calculated.I'm sorry beforehand that my code is messy:

```
k = 155900;
{rr2 = 2 k q1^2 q2 + 2 k q1 q2^2, 
  rr3 = q1^2 + 2 q1 q2 + (k^2 + 1) q2^2};
ee2 = k q1 q2;
ee3 = b2 /. Solve[2 b2 - σ^2 == 2 k* q2, {b2}];
oo5 = (-b1^2 + 2 (ee2) (ee3) == rr2);
{ee4, ee5} = b1 /. Solve[oo5, {b1}];
oo6 = (2 (ee2) + (ee3)^2 - 2 (ee5) σ == rr3);
oo8 = σ /. Solve[oo6, {σ}];
oo9 = Extract[oo8, {8}];

q2 = 0.05;
value1 = {b0 -> ee2, b1 -> ee5, b2 -> ee3};
value2 = {σ -> oo9};
calcJ[q1_] := 
 Module[{bd, X1, inverseX1, X2, X}, 
  bd = {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {-q2, k q2}, {q1, 0}};
  X1 = {{-b0 q1 q2 σ, b0 q1 q2 - b1 q1 q2 σ, 
     b1 q1 q2 - b2 q1 q2 σ, 
     b2 q1 q2 - k  q1 q2^2 - 
      q1 q2 σ^2}, {b0 q1^2 σ, -b0 q1^2 + k^2 q1^2 q2^2 +
       b1 q1^2 σ, -b1 q1^2 + b2 q1^2 σ, -b2 q1^2 + 
      2 k q1^2 q2 + q1^2 σ^2}, {-b0 b2 q1 q2 + k  b0 q1 q2^2 + 
      b0 q1 q2 σ^2, -b1 b2 q1 q2 + k  b1 q1 q2^2 - 
      b0 q1 q2 σ + b1 q1 q2 σ^2, 
     b0 q1 q2 - b2^2 q1 q2 + k  b2 q1 q2^2 - b1 q1 q2 σ + 
      b2 q1 q2 σ^2, 
     b1 q1 q2 - 2 b2 q1 q2 σ + k  q1 q2^2 σ + 
      q1 q2 σ^3}, {b0 b2 q1^2 - 2 k b0 q1^2 q2 - 
      b0 q1^2 σ^2, 
     b1 b2 q1^2 - 2 k b1 q1^2 q2 + b0 q1^2 σ - 
      b1 q1^2 σ^2, -b0 q1^2 + b2^2 q1^2 - 2 k b2 q1^2 q2 + 
      k^2 q1^2 q2^2 + b1 q1^2 σ - 
      b2 q1^2 σ^2, -b1 q1^2 + 2 b2 q1^2 σ - 
      2 k q1^2 q2 σ - q1^2 σ^3}};
  inverseX1 = Inverse[X1];
  X2 = {{-b0 q1^2 - b0 q1 q2, -b1 q1^2 - b1 q1 q2, -b2 q1^2 - 
      b2 q1 q2 + k  q1^2 q2, -q1^2 σ - 
      q1 q2 σ}, {b0 q1^2 + b0 q1 q2 - k^2 q1^2 q2^2, 
     b1 q1^2 + b1 q1 q2, 
     b2 q1^2 + b2 q1 q2 - 2 k q1^2 q2 - k  q1 q2^2, 
     q1^2 σ + q1 q2 σ}, {0, -k  q1^2 q2, 
     0, -q1^2 - q1 q2}, {-b0 b1 + 2 b0 b2 σ - 
      2 k b0 q2 σ - b0 σ^3, -b1^2 - b0 b2 + 2 k b0 q2 - 
      k  q1 q2^2 + 2 b1 b2 σ - 2 k b1 q2 σ + 
      b0 σ^2 - b1 σ^3, -2 b1 b2 + 2 k b1 q2 - 
      b0 σ + 2 b2^2 σ - 2 k b2 q2 σ + 
      b1 σ^2 - b2 σ^3, 
     b0 - b2^2 + 2 k b2 q2 - q1 q2 - (k^2 + 1) q2^2 - 2 b1 σ + 
      3 b2 σ^2 - 2 k q2 σ^2 - σ^4}};
  X = X2.inverseX1;
  (-Transpose[bd].X) /. value1 /. value2]

v = {143.5,66.4,29.8,5.6};
q1 = 1/v;

calcJ /@ q1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your assignment of a list to `q1` (second line from the end). It is used symbolically all over the place and that list gets inappropriately substituted into many expressions.

fix the last line to this:

```
 calcJ /@ 1/{143.5, 66.4, 29.8, 5.6}
```

Do not assign anything to `q1`. You should restart your kernel as well.

Comment: `calcJ /@ 1/v` perchance?

Comment: @george2079, @Edmund, I've tried changing into your suggestion. Tested and the result I get is when `v = {143.5}; calcJ /@ 1/v` gives the result of `(* {0.00696864} *)`  which is not the same as i'm looking above. What I'm trying to do is to calculate different value of `q1` inside the module. Since `q1=1/v` where `v={143.5, 66.4, 29.8, 5.6}`. Meaning here there's 4 different `q1` variables that need to be looped and calculated.